# How do I remove items using the D3.js remove function

Tags: d3.js

When I try to remove an element with the following code all my elements get set to "Updated" but none get removed. Adding new item to the list named "clients" works fine but not removing. What am I doing wrong? Here is the link to my code pen of the code.

```
let container = d3.select("#container");
    let clients = [{ Name: "Client0"
                   }];
    let count = 1;

    function addNewClient() {
        clients.push({Name: "Client" + count });
        count += 1;
        showData(clients);
    }

    function removeClient() {
        client = clients.slice(0,-1);
        count -= 1;
        showData(clients);
    }

    d3.csv(clients).then(showData); 

    function showData(data) {
        // join the data with all the yet to be created div tags
        let join = container
            .selectAll("div")
            .data(clients);
        // remove from screen those elements that do not have an associated data point
        join.exit().remove();
        // for each data point append a div
        join.enter()
            .append("div")
            .text(d => d.Name + " - New");

        join.text(d => d.Name + ": Updated");
    }

    showData(clients);

    function write(text) {
        container.append("div").text(text);
    }
```

Comment: Do you mean to use `client = clients.slice(0,-1)` as opposed to `clients = `, as you end up passing `clients` to `showData` -  currently `removeClient()` doesn't remove anything from the data array.

Comment: Thank you Andrew Reid! Wow, what a  silly mistake on my part.